# Docker-Machineを利用してaws上にインスタンスを作成したいのですが、うまくいきません。

Tags: aws, docker

docker-machineを使ってEC2のインスタンスを作成しようとしていますが、うまくいきません。ご享受お願いします。

Windows 10
Dokcer Toolbox使用

実行コマンド

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-open-port 8000 --amazonec2-region us-east-2 --amazonec2-vpc-id vpc-7c62aa17  --amazonec2-subnet-id subnet-2774e56b aws-sandbox
```

ホームディレクトリの下に~/.aws/credentialsを作成

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

~/.aws/config

```
[default]
region = us-east-2
output=json
```

エラー文

```
Error setting machine configuration from flags provided: AuthFailure: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials
        status code: 401, request id: 2831b0fd-84b1-4948-b1d8-0d7216960220
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージを見る限りは、AWS への認証が通っていないエラーです。まずは設定されている credentials で認証が通るかどうかを確認してください。つまり、docker-machine 側の問題ではないのか、docker-machine 側の問題なのかを確認してください。

たとえばシェルで AWS CLI を使い `aws sts get-caller-identity` を実行して [GetCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html) が通るかどうか確認してください（[参考](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31836816/5989200)）。

認証が通ってないようであれば、その原因を探ってください。たとえばパソコンの時刻が同期されていないときに認証が通らないことが知られています: [Linux インスタンスの時刻の設定](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html)